# ColdFusion site: re-direct to new Word document location

Tags: redirect, coldfusion, docx

I have a Coldfusion site where we are simplifying the folder structure.  It's easy to re-direct requests for .cfm pages that are moving: in Application.cfm, just capture the URL of the requested page and massage it a little. For example, http:||mycoldfusionsite.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/something.cfm becomes http:||mycoldfusionsite.com/folder1/something.cfm (I'm using pipes instead of slashes because these are not real links), and use cflocation to present the page at its new location.

However, our site also has a folder where we store Word documents, but I cannot perform a re-direct in Application.cfm like this: http:||mycoldfusionsite.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/documents/Happy.docx to http:||mysharepointsite.com/documents/Happy.docx (please note that the new location is on a totally different site, a SharePoint site).

I suspect that this is because the document being requested is not a .cfm file, and therefore Application.cfm is not being invoked.

How can I perform this redirect for non-cfm files?

Thanks!

Comment: Have one .cfm page that reads the file in question and offers it to the user with cfheader/cfcontent.

Comment: The case we are trying to handle is when the user has saved a link to the document in the old location. How would your solution work in that case?  Would it?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I misspoke above.  The new location for the Word documents is a totally different site, a SharePoint site, if that makes any difference. Original post edited.